# How i can reference static files inside my asp.net MVC core web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 excel sheets inside my Asp.net core MVC web application under a folder named "Files" as follow:-

[image]

now i want to reference these files inside my TextFieldParser method as follow:-

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Sync()
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("*******"))
```

so how i can do so?

Second question, inside my `startup.cs` i have the following `app.UseStaticFiles();` as follow:-

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {

            }
            else
            {

            app.UseStaticFiles();
```

so does this mean that users can access the files directly? as in my case i do not want users to have the ability to view or download the files, i only want to reference the files inside the above code.
Thanks

Comment: There is two methods to call, one is Content Root Path and second is Web Root Path. Web Root Path is your wwwroot folder. As shown in your picture, your files are situated in Content Root Path. It means you need to call IWebHostEnvironment and use ContentRootPath and then add string "Files\.....". But as I understand in your server you will need to give those file permission of IISUSERS to modify them.

Comment: @Artavazd can you advice more on ur reply.?

Comment: Just add IWebHostEnvironment to your constructor and make an protected field of it, they call it and use ContentRoot, then add to that string the rest of your file path.

Comment: @Artavazd is there any doc or example on how to do so?

Comment: Will prepare detailed description and let you know from 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that this code will help you in some cases.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    protected IWebHostEnvironment _host; // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _host = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string YOURCURRENTFILE = _host.ContentRootPath + @"/File/v2.csv";
        // USE YOUR TextFieldParser logic
    }
}
```